# Odd input/output error running the latest version of Knoppix

Tags: bash, sudo, knoppix

I have this error when I try to do most things..

```
bash: /usr/bin/program: Input/output error
```

This is a fresh install of the latest Knoppix, running off of a USB. The hash is correct,
so I don't know what it really could be.

Some `dmesg` output:

```
[ 1422.551305] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.551567] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.551832] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.552106] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.552367] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.552635] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.552907] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.553185] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.553476] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.553729] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.554017] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.554350] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1422.554678] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1481.701353] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1481.701356] print_req_error: 34 callbacks suppressed
[ 1481.701358] print_req_error: I/O error, dev cloop0, sector 6375040 flags 0
[ 1481.701615] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1481.701617] print_req_error: I/O error, dev cloop0, sector 6375040 flags 0
[ 1481.702060] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1481.702062] print_req_error: I/O error, dev cloop0, sector 6375216 flags 0
[ 1481.702319] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1481.702321] print_req_error: I/O error, dev cloop0, sector 6375216 flags 0
[ 1633.631162] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
[ 1633.631170] print_req_error: I/O error, dev cloop0, sector 6375040 flags 0
[ 1633.631815] cloop: decompression error -3 uncompressing block 12451 70223 bytes @ 1154490597, flags 0
```

Full dmesg output: http://0x0.st/i5py.json

Comment: Most likely caused by errors reading from the drive.  Can you run `dmesg` to see if it reports errors?  Have you tried using the same image on a different USB drive?